# Spring 3 - Security: How to rebuild authManager () usage?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I try to go from Spring-Boot 2.7 to 3.1 - its regarding Security.

What I have under old version 2.

```
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Override
    protected void configure (HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {   
        http.cors ().and ()
            .csrf ().disable ()
            .authorizeRequests ()       
            .antMatchers ("/web/test").permitAll ()             
            .antMatchers ("/web/**").hasAnyRole ("USER")
            .anyRequest ().authenticated ()             
            .and ()
            .addFilter (new SecurityAuthenticationFilter (authenticationManager ()))
            .addFilter (new SecurityAuthorizationFilter (authenticationManager ()))      
            .sessionManagement ()
            .sessionCreationPolicy (SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
```

What I already have for version 3.

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain (HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{
    http
        .cors (Customizer.withDefaults ())
         .csrf (AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
        .authorizeHttpRequests ((requests) -> requests
            .requestMatchers ("/web/test").permitAll ()
            .requestMatchers ("/web/**").hasRole ("USER")
            .anyRequest ().authenticated ()           
        )
        //.addFilter (new SecurityAuthenticationFilter (authenticationManager ()))
        
        .sessionManagement (httpSecuritySessionManagementConfigurer -> 
            httpSecuritySessionManagementConfigurer.sessionCreationPolicy (SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))

        ;

    return http.build();
```

But here I struggle with authenticationManager () of former WebSecurtyConfigurationAdapter - for my 2 custom filters.

They are

```
public class SecurityAuthorizationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter
{
    public SecurityAuthorizationFilter (AuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
    {
        super (authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException 
    {
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken upa = getAuthentication (request);
        if (upa == null)
        {
            filterChain.doFilter (request, response);
        }
        else
        {
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext ().setAuthentication (upa);
            filterChain.doFilter (request, response);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings ("unchecked")
    private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthentication (HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        String token = request.getHeader (SecurityConstants.TOKEN_HEADER);
        
        if (token != null && token.startsWith (SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX) == true)
        {
            byte [] signingKey = SecurityConstants.JWT_SECRET.getBytes ();
            token = token.replace (SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX, "");
            
            Jws <Claims> claim = Jwts.parserBuilder ().setSigningKey (signingKey).build ().parseClaimsJws (token);
            String usr = claim.getBody ().getSubject ();
            
            List <LinkedHashMap <?, ?>> cs = claim.getBody ().get ("roles", List.class);
            List <SimpleGrantedAuthority> claims  = new ArrayList <SimpleGrantedAuthority> ();
            for (int i = 0; i < cs.size (); i ++)
            {
                claims.add (new SimpleGrantedAuthority (cs.get (i).get ("authority"). toString ()));
            }
            
            if (usr.length () > 0) 
            {
                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken (usr, null, claims);
            }
        }
        
        return null;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class SecurityAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter 
{
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    
    
    
    public SecurityAuthenticationFilter (AuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
    {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        setFilterProcessesUrl (SecurityConstants.AUTH_LOGIN_URL);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    {
        String usr = request.getParameter ("username");
        String pwd = request.getParameter ("password");
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken upat = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken (usr, pwd); 
        return authenticationManager.authenticate (upat);
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain, Authentication authentication) throws java.io.IOException, ServletException
    {
        UserDetails user = ((UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal ());
      
        @SuppressWarnings ("unchecked")
        Collection <GrantedAuthority> roles = (Collection <GrantedAuthority>) user.getAuthorities ();   
        String token = Jwts.builder ()
            .signWith (Keys.hmacShaKeyFor (SecurityConstants.JWT_SECRET.getBytes ()), SignatureAlgorithm.HS512)
            .setHeaderParam ("typ", SecurityConstants.TOKEN_TYPE)
            .setIssuer (SecurityConstants.TOKEN_ISSUER)
            .setAudience (SecurityConstants.TOKEN_AUDIENCE)
            .setSubject (user.getUsername ())
            .setExpiration (new java.util.Date (System.currentTimeMillis () + 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000))     // 24h lifetime of token          
            .claim ("roles", roles)
            .compact ();

        response.addHeader (SecurityConstants.TOKEN_HEADER, SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX + token);
    }
}
```

**Question**

How can I integration my 2 filters in Spring3 security??
authManager () is not available there.

Comment: It is not clear what are you asking. Clarify you problem and add details.

Comment: In my Spring2 Config there is authenticationManager (). That is not available in the new for Spring3. How can I make my 2 Filters going?

Comment: Your problem is that handing out JWTs to browsers is considered dangerous by nomerous security sources including the spring security team themselfes. Thats why it is not working, and you should instead follow the security standards that exist like oauth2/open id connect or traditional session based login. Good luck